# css keyframe animation is not showing on the browser

Tags: css, keyframe

my @keyframe CSS code seems alright. its not giving error yet its not showing at all on the browser.
the classname on html is img1.
my @keyframe CSS code seems alright. its not giving error yet its not showing at all on the browser.
the classname on html is img1.
somebody help

```css
.img1 {
  width: 150px;
  animation-name: pics;
  animation-duration: 25s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  background-image: url("assets/pic1.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 19px;
}

@keyframes pics {
  0% {
    background-image: url("assets/pic8.jpg");
  }

  12.5% {
    background-image: url("assets/pic1.png");
  }

  25% {
    background-image: url("assets/pic2.png");
  }

  37.5% {
    background-image: url("assets/pic3.jpg");
  }

  50% {
    background-image: url("assets/pic4.jpg");
  }

  62.5% {
    background-image: url("assets/pic5.jpg");
  }

  75% {
    background-image: url("assets/pic6.jpg");
  }

  87.5% {
    background-image: url("assets/pic7.jpg");
  }

  100% {
    background-image: url("assets/pic8.jpg");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yo added this class to `<img>`?

Comment: What is the height of your element which has class ".img1" ? have you check that? if element have no height you can not able to view the background image. also can you please share js fiddle or HTML code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your animation is working, but as @Yudiz says you need to set a height to your `.img1` element.

`background-image` property is setting a background image to your element, but il will not change his size depending of your background-image size. Right now, your `.img1` element is 150px large, and 0px tall, so it's invisible.